# Python avoiding large array allocation multiple times

Tags: python-3.x

I have to compute a function many many times. 
To compute this function the elements of an array must be computed. 
The array is quite large.

How can I avoid the allocation of the array in every function call.

The code I have tried goes *something* like this:

```
class FunctionCalculator(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        """
        Get the data and do some small handling of it
        Let's say that we do
        self.data = data
        """
    def function(self, point):
        return numpy.sum(numpy.array([somecomputations(item) for item in self.data]))
```

Well, maybe my concern is unfounded, so I have first this question.

**Question:** Is it true that the array `[somecomputations(item) for item in data]` is being allocated and deallocated for every call to `function`?

Thinking that that is the case I have tried

```
class FunctionCalculator(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        """
        Get the data and do some small handling of it
        Let's say that we do
        self.data = data
        """
        self.number_of_data = range(0, len(data))
        self.my_array = numpy.zeros(len(data))
    def function(self, point):
        for i in self.number_of_data:
            self.my_array[i] = somecomputations(self.data[i])
        return numpy.sum(self.my_array)
```

This is slower than the previous version. I assume that the list comprehension in the first version can be ran in C entirely, while in the second version smaller parts of the script can be translated into optimized C code.

I have very little idea of how Python works inside.

**Question:** Is there a good way to skip the array allocation in every function call and at the same time take advantage of a well optimized loop on the array?

I am using Python3.5

Answer (score 1):

Looping over the array is unnecessary and access python to c many times, hence the slow down. The beauty of numpy arrays that functions work on them cell by cell. I think the fastest would be:

```
return numpy.sum(somecomputations(self.data))
```

Somecomputations may need a bit of a modification, but often it will work off the bat. Also, you're not using point, and other stuff.

Comment: In order to pass the numpy array to my function does the function have to consists of operations numpy knows about? I didn't quite understand.

Comment: Oh! I just learned there is a `numpy.vectorize`, to which you pass a function. That might help.

Comment: It's not a must. Functions which are simple arithmetic expression work as is.